# Maven - Is there a way to specify a flag in mvn install to not run a specific plugin?

Tags: maven

I already searched and found out that you can create a profile and a plugin that will run only for that profile, then in build you can specify that it will include that profile.

Unfortunately, for my case, it won't work, because I have a plugin that must run everytime, and I want to be able to specify a flag so it won't execute.

I already thought on adding a global profile (that would be active by default) to execute the plugin, and when I want the plugin to not be executed, disable it with flag `-P !profile_id`, but it doesn't seem as a good idea because I want to be able to share my code and pom and it should work for every other developer and don't force them on creating this active profile.

Comment: The question is: What kind of plugin do you need to control?

Comment: @khmarbaise it is a plugin to run grunt on compile phase. I want to be able to set a flag and stop grunt execution

Comment: a lot of plugins support some sort of "skip" parameter to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I searched on plugin page and found out there is a specific flag to block grunt execution!